# What does manager interview mean for fresher?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, hiring

Industry: IT

Hi, I just received an email from HR that I have cleared the technical round and I would have a final manager interview round.

I think experienced professionals would be asked to share their experience from past/current organization and how was the culture there, how would they manage a team etc.

But how does it look like for a fresher? I have never worked in a company so I don't know what questions I would be asked?

Comment: I guess the manager (and maybe your soon to be coworkers) wants to get to know you a bit in terms of personality & technical skills. He might want to introduce you to the team and their way of getting the job done..

Comment: This is 100% normal.  It's likely they will only ask you some social questions - where do you live, sports, etc.  Just to get to know you.  Best of luck!

Comment: Yup, they just want to get a first look to make sure you're not rubbing them the wrong way during a normal conversation and to make sure your views don't clash too badly with theirs. If you can talk together in a civilized manner then all is well. The first several months/year of your contract are then spent training you to fit in and become productive instead of money sink.

Comment: There could still be general situational questions even if you don't have professional experience - like, did you work with groups for large projects while in school, how would you handle an example disagreement, what would you do if you realized you couldn't get work done in time, and so on. I agree that the hardest part is probably over. Good luck!

Comment: I interview everyone we are considering bringing into my group. Pretty much a standard management function.

Answer (score 24):

It is not about experienced or fresher. Most likely it is just about having that final check, gauge your work attitude and personality. If everyone is happy, make that call to the HR to release the offer letter. Standard process. If you have already cleared your technical interview, just be pleasant and nice, and everything will be fine.

Comment: And confident. Don't think you can do the job, know you can do the job. Because if you've made it this far, you can.